# Realizar pruebas unitarias a una clase tipo sealed que contiene internamente clases privadas

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias

Tengo una clase de tipo `sealed` que contiene algunas clases privadas internas con métodos públicos dentro de ellas.

Mi tarea es probar los métodos públicos que se hallan dentro de esas clases privadas, pero sé de antemano que los métodos (incluyendo los `void`), `properties` y `fields` de tipo `private` no pueden ser probados. En teoría deberían existir métodos públicos que hagan uso de estos elementos privados, pero no los hay (o sea, que prácticamente no puedo tener acceso a lo que quiero por ningún lado).

[Aquí](https://pastebin.com/BWLXMRQD) dejo la clase que quiero probar. Las líneas que necesito probar son de la 421 en adelante. A lo único que si tengo acceso son a los métodos públicos de la clase sealed.

Muchas gracias de antemano. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Buenas ArCiGo, intenta siempre poner el código en la pregunta, ya que si el enlace que compartes se cae no se podrá acceder a él y entonces ya no serviría tu pregunta.

Comment: @Marc Tienes toda la razón, pero no quise poner las casi 868 líneas de código que son (y hace rato que quise poner el código me excedí del límite de caracteres, por eso no pude actualizar el post). ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

para lograr lo que quieres debes de usar Reflection, aqui te envio el link donde se explica muy bien el tema

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Ademas te envio un ejemplo que realice y probe en un proyecto de tipo consola

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrivateClassPublicMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        sealed class GeneralClass
        {
            private class MyClass
            {
                public void Sum(int a, int b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a+b);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.Name.Equals("MyClass"))
                {
                    var myMethod = type.GetMethod("Sum");
                    object t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    var para = new object[]{1,2};

                    myMethod.Invoke(t, para);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo el ejemplo, y lo seguí tal cual para mi caso, pero mi clase está en otra librería y no puedo tener acceso a las clases a través de esta forma que propones (solamente puedo ver los métodos privados/internos de las clases que están dentro de la misma librería)

Comment: carga el assembly y despues trabajalo, aqui te envio la pagina que explica como hacerlo, si quieres un ejemplo me dices y te lo hago                          https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He intentado de la manera que mencionabas. Me detecta mi clase sealed, MessageHub, pero no me detecta las clases internas dentro de ella (nunca entra al if porque está comparando el nombre de la clase sealed con la de la privada). Muéstrame el ejemplo de cómo quedaría, por favor

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te envío un primer bloque. Sigue las indicaciones, luego coge esa .dll que se genera y pégala en una ruta sencilla, digamos en tu escritorio, y pruebas con el proyecto en consola que te envío más abajo también. Espero que resuelvas tu problema.

1) Crea un proyecto de tipo librería de clase con este primer bloque de código que te separo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classOut
{
    sealed class ClassSealedL
    {
        private class MyClassPrivateLibrary
        {
            public void Sum(int a, int b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a+b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí la librería de clases.

2) Proyecto de consola para probar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using classOut;

namespace PrivateClassPublicMethod
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\danis\Desktop\classOut.dll");
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();


            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.Name.Equals("MyClassPrivateLibrary"))
                {
                    var myMethod = type.GetMethod("Sum");
                    object t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    var para = new object[] { 10, 2 };

                    myMethod.Invoke(t, para);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vale, vale. Lo checo y te comento si funcionó